# Speed up patterns creation while generating patterns to be added to Phrase Matcher in Spacy

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy

Trying to recognize entities from a given piece of text using Spacy's phraseMatcher in a flask application.

I have a custom list of entities (around 150 K) that I want to match against using Spacy's phraseMatcher . I am using the fastest recommended approach using the tokenizer.pipe as specified [here](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#phrasematcher) while creating the patterns and also for adding to the PhraseMatcher.

```py
with open('entities_index_keys.pkl', 'rb')as f:
    entities_list=pickle.load(f)

print (len(entities_list))

phrase_matcher_obj = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)

# create doc for each entity from entities_list
patterns = list(nlp.tokenizer.pipe(entities_list))
phrase_matcher_obj.add('my_entities', None, *patterns)
```

The line below takes a while to complete. I had success with an entity list of size 1200, and that was pretty fast at runtime as well. But when going to 150 K entities, it slows down significantly.

```py
patterns = list(nlp.tokenizer.pipe(entities_list))
```

I would rather avoid creating the patterns at runtime but pickling the list of "docs"/patterns created using above code corrupts the object for some reason. So is there a way to create the patterns and add to the phrasematcher object on the fly fast without taking a speed hit?

Another alternate approach would be to save the PhraseMatcher to disk and just load it fast during the execution of the flask app route. (tried pickling with no success)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to pickle a `PhraseMatcher`. Unpickling isn't extremely fast because it has to rebuild some internal data structures, but it doesn't have to retokenize the texts and should be faster than building from scratch. Because of some bugfixes, I'd recommend v2.2.2+.

If you run into errors pickling a `PhraseMatcher`, please submit a bug report in the issue tracker.